# Kendo UI TreeView Drag and Drop get the destination (dropped) treeview object

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, drag-and-drop, kendo-treeview

I have two TreeViews structure with drag and drop functionality. 
The nodes from both the Treeviews can be dragged and dropped on one another.

**If I am dragging some content from source to destination i want updated list of destination in console**

For reference you can check [link here](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treeview/dragdrop).

In this DEMO I can move something from one category to another but I want to capture the updated list of category containing all the subcategory.

Here is the snippet of my code

```
<div id="example">
        <div class="demo-section k-content">
            <h4>Treeview One</h4>
            <div id="treeview-left"></div>
            <h4 style="padding-top: 2em;">Treeview Two</h4>
            <div id="treeview-right"></div>
        </div>

        <script>
            $("#treeview-left").kendoTreeView({
                dragAndDrop: true,
                dataSource: [
                    { text: "Furniture", expanded: true, items: [
                        { text: "Tables & Chairs" },
                        { text: "Sofas" },
                        { text: "Occasional Furniture" }
                    ] },
                    { text: "Decor", items: [
                        { text: "Bed Linen" },
                        { text: "Curtains & Blinds" },
                        { text: "Carpets" }
                    ] }
                ]
            });

            $("#treeview-right").kendoTreeView({
                dragAndDrop: true,
                dataSource: [
                    { text: "Storage", expanded: true, items: [
                        { text: "Wall Shelving" },
                        { text: "Floor Shelving" },
                        { text: "Kids Storage" }
                    ]
                    },
                    { text: "Lights", items: [
                        { text: "Ceiling" },
                        { text: "Table" },
                        { text: "Floor" }
                    ]
                    }
                ]
            });
        </script>
```

how can I achieve this? 
Thank you

Comment: Please share your code of what have you attempted so far

Comment: @RahulGupta I have updated my question please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a [**JsFiddle DEMO here**](https://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/w36v4v3h/).

You will need to bind the [`dragend event`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/treeview#events-dragend) of both of your Treeviews to a function and then you can get the destination Treeview list from there. Here is the snippet from the DEMO:

```
function tree_dragend(e) {
  alert("See your console");
  console.log("Drag end sourceNode = ", e.sourceNode, "dropPosition = ", e.dropPosition, "destinationNode = ", e.destinationNode);

  var destinationTreeviewDOMElement = $( e.destinationNode ).closest( "div.k-treeview" );
  console.log("destinationTreeviewDOMElement = ", destinationTreeviewDOMElement);

  var destinationTreeview = $(destinationTreeviewDOMElement).data("kendoTreeView");
  console.log("destinationTreeview = ", destinationTreeview);

  console.log("destinationTreeviewData = ", destinationTreeview.dataSource.data());
}

var treeview_left = $("#treeview-left").data("kendoTreeView");
var treeview_right = $("#treeview-right").data("kendoTreeView");

treeview_left.bind("dragend", tree_dragend);
treeview_right.bind("dragend", tree_dragend);
```